# enable disable cfselect

Tags: coldfusion, cfform

how can I disable cfselect while using html form format, or make cfselect view only? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<cfselect disabled="disabled">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp